# What are some causes of amp clipping aside from those related to exceeding the rail voltage

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, signal, voltage-clipping

I often encounter problems where an amp may exhibit clipping despite the input signal being well below the rail voltage. I understand that there are numerous problems that cause this.

However, what are the some common reasons as to why such clipping may occur? I am not looking for specific circuit designs but rather mistakes/problems such as inputting a signal that exceeds the common mode range.

Answer (score 4):

If you load your Opamp output     down with a low load resistance you can get clipping when the output stage of the opamp goes into current limiting .This can occur when  all the pins are far away from the supply rails.

Answer (score 0):

Classic problem: broadband input with lots of thermal random noise at 100milliVolt RMS total integrated noise; VDD allows 2 volts peak-peak; designer provided 40dB gain (100X) to the narrowband signal which had level of only 10 milliVolts.

See the problem? Expected output, of the signal, was 10mV * 100 = 1vpp.

But the RMS noise output (broad band) was 100mV * 100 = 10 volts RMS, or about
60 volts peak-peak 6 sigma.